# Cannot POST to a route from and HTML form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a nodejs/expressjs application and this is my architecture:
 + routes
   - candidate.js
   - index.js
 + views
   - layout.vash
   - register.vash
 - server.js

in my server.js file, I put this code to manage routes:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var candidate = require('./routes/candidate');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/candidate', candidate);
```

in candidate.js, all get requests work fine, but there is a problem in post requests, it can't resolve the path: Cannot POST /caregister

### server.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var candidate = require('./routes/candidate');
var employer = require('./routes/employer');


var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'vash');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/candidate', candidate);
app.use('/employer', employer);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('server is listening to ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

### routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

### routes/candidate.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Candidate = require("../models/candidate");

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('candidatelogin'); // relative to candidatelogin.vash
});


router.post('/caregister',  function(req, res){

    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var passwordConf = req.body.passwordConf;


    console.log(username + " " + email);

});


module.exports = router;
```

### views/candidatelogin.vash

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model){
    @html.block('body', function(model){
        <h1>Jobseeker</h>

        <div id="register">
            <h3>Create new Account</h3>
            <form method="post" action="/caregister">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br/><br/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br/><br/>
                <input type="password" name="passwordConf" placeholder="password confirmation"><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </form>
        </div>
    })
})
```

Comment: You should place `candidate` route in top of `index` route.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin the same problem

Comment: Cam you post the contents of those files?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `app.use` and including a prefix like `candidate` that means that you should use this prefix to access this route later on.

So your form in `candidatelogin.vash` should post to `/candidate/caregister` url:

```
    <div id="register">
        <h3>Create new Account</h3>
        <form method="post" action="/candidate/caregister">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br/><br/>
            <input type="password" name="passwordConf" placeholder="password confirmation"><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
```